# How to read a CSV by column name in Java

Tags: java, json, csv

I have a Java program that uses `org.json` to read and parse a CSV file into JSON format. However I'm not sure how to approach it with this format CSV.[image]

I need to grab the data labels from the column, make sure it's the most recent entry, and then add them to a JSON object.

How would I go about this if you have to create a new jObject with each iteration? My code goes line by line and I'm not sure how to create the proper output.

```
if(reader != null){
                         //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                         String aux = "";
                         while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             jObject = new JSONObject();
                             String[] tab = aux.split(",");
                             if (count > 0){
                                jObject = new JSONObject();
                                jObject.put("time", tab[0]);
                                jObject.put("total", tab[1]);
                                jObject.put("Natural Gas", tab[2]);
                                jObject.put("Other Fossil Fuels", tab[3]);
                                jObject.put("Dual Fuel", tab[4]);
                                jObject.put("Nuclear", tab[5]);
                                jObject.put("Hydro", tab[6]);
                                jObject.put("Wind", tab[7]);
                                jObject.put("Other Renewables", tab[8]);
                                jObject.put("Unknown", tab[9]);
                                jArray.put(jObject);
                            }
```

The final output should be something like this:

```
[{
"time":"2015-07-01 04:00:00",
"total" : "19474"  
  data : [{
  "name" : "Natural Gas",
  "load" :"1736"
   },{
    "name" : "Dual",
    "load" : "8366"
   } etc.
```

instead it's like this:

```
[{"Natural Gas":"1736","total":"19474","Nuclear":"5352","time":"2015-07-01 04:00:00","Other Renewables":"349","Unknown":" ","Hydro":"3003","Dual Fuel":"8366","Wind":"393","Other Fossil Fuels":"275"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a count and if it was the first line (column names) I saved it as one string and if it was the latest I saved it as another.

```
String lastLineMinusOne = "";
String lastLine = "";
String firstLine = "";
                         while ((aux = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                             if(count == 0)firstLine = aux;
                             lastLineMinusOne = lastLine;
                             lastLine = aux;
                             count ++;
                            }
                         String[] first = firstLine.split(",");
                         String[] last = lastLine.split(",");
```